# How do you get run-time html in C#

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to extract a few HTML nodes from a webpage.  I use the following code to get the webpage source.  However, this does not return the "final" html source that I see in my web browser.   It appears that the webpage has some script that generates the html nodes that I need.  How I get the final version of the html source that I see in my web browser?

```
public static string GetWebText(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.UserAgent = "SimpleWebcrawler";

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return htmlText;
}
```

Comment: Are you writing a Windows Forms application? If so make use of the WebBrowser control

Comment: I tried using a WebBroswer control. I didn't see how it could be used to view the final HTML text.  It showed me the same HTML with the script and not the HTML nodes I needed.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something.  The WebBrower control shows the webpage correctly but the DocumentText Property only shows the webpage source with the script and not the HTML nodes that I need.

Comment: Is that node loaded by Ajax call  ? If so try to handle DocumentCompleted event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.documentElement.outerHTML/innerHTML` to get client-side HTML. You can process it by JS on client or by `WebMethod` on server

Answer (score 0):

Try following with `WebBrowser` control

```
if(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    // Get the HTML here and use this.webBrowser1.Document
}
```

Otherwise use the `DocumentCompleted` event to get the HTML